# How to Enable Fingerprint Login in Ubuntu 20.04 lenova ideapad 3

Tags: fingerprint-reader, ideapad

These my lsusb;

- Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
- Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c57 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
- Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b6ce Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
- Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp.
- Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
- Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Hello. This is the only one of concern based on the question. Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c57 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint Do you have the driver for it? What kernel are you running?

Comment: As per the excellent resource that is Linux-Hardware.org, [there is no known driver](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:04f3-0c57) for that fingerprint reader 

Comment: I have not tried this myself. Try at your own risk. https://www.tec4tric.com/linux/enable-fingerprint-login-in-ubuntu